# Is it possible to map SQL Server XML column in OrmLite?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ormlite-servicestack

We have a field in our database (SQL Server 2008) that of type "XML".

Is it possible to map this into an ORMLite (ServiceStack 3.9.35) model?  What datatype would be used?

Answer (score 0):

All return query is xml can that.

```
Sql query =    
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

SELECT e.BusinessEntityID AS [@BusinessEntityID]
      ,e.JobTitle AS [@JobTitle]
      ,e.BirthDate AS [@BirthDate]
      ,j.Resume AS '*'
  FROM [HumanResources].[Employee] e
  INNER JOIN [HumanResources].JobCandidate j
  ON e.BusinessEntityID = j.BusinessEntityID
  for xml PATH('Employee'), root('Employees');

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SQL Query ");
using (var Db = OpenDbConnection())
        {
            IDbCommand cmd = Db.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 240;
            cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            var lekérdezett = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(lekérdezett);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;
                StreamReader reader= new StreamReader(stream);
                var str = reader.ReadLine();
                NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsNull(str, string.Format("Az str változó null értéken van:{0}", str.ToString()));
            }
```